# How to scrape multiple pages when link query parameters have number of items instead of page numbers?

Tags: python

Recently started coding in Python and this is officially my first post on Stack Overflow. I'm working on a personal project where I'm trying to scrape data (using Beautiful Soup) from the [H&M website](https://www2.hm.com/en_in/men/shop-by-product/tshirts-tank-tops.html)

The idea is to print a list of newly added products in a particular product category (Men's T-shirts in this case) every time the script runs. Eventually, I'll also set this up with email.

I've managed to get this to work for the first page (36 products) but I'd like to scrape data for all the products. What's the best way of doing that? Also, I would not want to define the total number of products as a constant because they may change every now and then.

Here's my code so far:

```
"""
1. Get the H&M t-shirts web page.
    - Use requests library to get the html for the page that needs scraping.
2. Extract/Parse useful info: Name of the product, price, colours, link to the product.
    - Identify the html tags which have the relevant info
    - Use beautiful soup Library to extract info
3. Send the extracted info into a csv file
4. If running for the first time (no prior data), end the program here.
5. If running the program again, compare the two csv files somehow and print the new entries on console?

"""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www2.hm.com/en_in/men/shop-by-product/tshirts-tank-tops.html'
HM_URL_PREFIX = 'https://www2.hm.com'

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}


def main():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    # Grab each product
    product_elems = soup.find_all('li', class_='product-item')

    filename = 'products.csv'
    f = open(filename, 'w')

    headers = 'Product Name, Price, Link\n'
    f.write(headers)

    for product_elem in product_elems:
        product_name = product_elem.div.next_sibling.h3.a.string
        product_price = product_elem.div.next_sibling.strong.span.string
        product_link = HM_URL_PREFIX + product_elem.div.a['href']

        # print('product name: ' + product_name)
        # print('product price: ' + product_price)
        # print('product link: ' + product_link)
        # print(end='\n' * 3)
        f.write(product_name + ',' + product_price.replace(',', '') + ',' + product_link + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

be warned H&m might not want you to do this, see hm.com/robots.txt for how they want you to interact with the site. Not following the rules in this file might expose you to push back from H&M, I can't recommend you that you that you take any of the following suggestions.

When you click on the load more products button on the page you are redirected to a url with a query string:

```
https://www2.hm.com/en_in/men/shop-by-product/tshirts-tank-tops.html?product-type=men_tshirtstanks&sort=stock&image-size=small&image=model&offset=0&page-size=72
```

you can edit the `page-size=72` variable at the end of the string to make it return more products or fewer products. [see here for more info on query strings.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

You could also look at this project for more details `https://www.programmableweb.com/api/unofficial-hm-rest-api-v1`
but I couldn't necessarily recommend it as it is not an official api

You could also dig through all the various javascript files they have on their pages to see if there is a specific url or script getting the data in a more compact format than pulling all the html and images down.